# Proguard with an Android app returns error

Tags: android, proguard

The `project.properties`:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

**[edit]**
according to : 
http://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/discussion/182456/thread/e4d73acf

using 
-keepnames class com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }

compiled is ok, finally.....

Answer (score 0):

According to your exception content, I guess it might be `android.os.Bundle`'s obfuscation problem. Try adding

```
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

to your progard file.If it still not work, show us more about the exception info plz.